# Creating a new column in pyspark dataframe using another column values from future

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 3-columns and I wanted to create a new column using values of column projection.
How the values should be picked from projection?--It should pick 3-consective values of projection year wise for ex - if you are creating a new column for year 2020 the value it should pick from 2021,2022,2023

I have tried below sql:

spark.sql(''' select serial_number,pit_pd_proj as proj1,year,lead(pit_pd_proj,3) over(partition by serial_number order by year) as proj2 from  table where serial_number = 1 order by year''').show(50,truncate=False)

but this is not the complete answer

[image: I wanted the projection2 column as the output]

Comment: Has any of the answers able to solve your problem. if yes please accept and upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

lag functions can be used to get previous values (before that proper sort / order by is needed). https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lag.html

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("year")
df = df.withColumn("prev_value", F.lag(df.projection).over(my_window))
```

If you add to question example table with desired output (as there is only source) I can try to replicate it and update answer (above is not tested).

Comment: I have added my desired o/p in the question basically I wanted to create a new column called projection2 using the formula - projection2 at 2020 should have the value equal to sum of values at projection column starting 2021 till 2023 and so on

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by making use of window function and row frame.I am providing the answer in Scala ,but definitely the same can be implemented using Python as well.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df=Seq(("1","358934","2020"),("1","38639","2021"),("1","983434","2022"),("1","234","2023"),("1","2325","2024"),("1","4545","2025"),("1","7675","2026")).toDF("serial_number","projection","year")

val partitionExpr=Window.orderBy("year").rowsBetween(1, 3)

df.withColumn("total",sum("projection") over(partitionExpr)).show(false)
```

For additional information on Row and Range,please refer to
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html